# En Rmarkdown quiero poner una tabla de contenidos que se titule "Índice" (en ESP) y no "Contents" (ING)

Tags: latex, indices, markdown, r-markdown

Estoy haciendo mi TFG con Rmarkdown y quiero que aparezca tras la portada un índice cuyo encabezado sea "Índice" y no "Contents" como me sale por defecto

Sé incluir un `\tableofcontents` pero no consigo que salga como **Índice** en vez de como *Contents*

¿Alguna ayuda?

Incluyo el código

````
---
title: El concepto de naturaleza humana en Karl Polanyi y la función política de los Derechos
blinded: 0
authors: 
  
- name: Alberto Baeza Vaz
  thanks: El autor agradece al Ministerio de Educación por la concesión de la Beca de colaboración con el Departamento de Ciencias Políticas y de la Administración de la Universidad de Granada para el curso 2020/2021.
  affiliation: Facultad de Ciencias Políticas y Sociología, Universidad de Granada

keywords:
- 3 to 6 keywords
- that do not appear in the title
abstract: |
  The text of your abstract.  200 or fewer words.
lang: es
papersize: a4
fontsize: 12
csl: apa.csl
bibliography: tfgref.bib
output: rticles::asa_article
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: sentence
---
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage```
````

Comment: Bienvenido Alberto Baeza a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que hay dos formas:

#### Redefinir los nombres

En este caso se trataría de `\contentsname`, que puedes definirlo en la cabezera del `Rmd`:

```
header-includes:
   - \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contenidos}
```

aunque también el comando funcionaría en el cuerpo del documento:

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contenidos}
```

---

#### Usar un paquete como `babel` para localizar el documento

Esto puede ser más cómodo por que te traducirá múltiples nombres

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

---

Ver:

- [How to change the title of ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/how-to-change-the-title-of-toc)
- [How to include LaTeX package in R Markdown?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown)